# How to remove duplicate image textures?

Tags: texturing, image, blend-files

So I have appended a lot of characters into my scene from separate blend files which all use some identical image textures. My problem is that when they are appended each, the image textures are duplicated even though they are the exact same image.

I end up with "Image.png, Image.png.001, Image.png.002, Image.png.003, etc"

Is there any possible way I can remove all of these duplicate images and only have one that is used by all of the models?

A script maybe? I have zero experience with scripts unfortunately so I'd need a good explanation as to how to do it.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can use the *Remap Users* function in Outliner.

1. Go to *Outliner > Blender File > Images* category.
2. Select images with the .001/.002... appendix.
3. <kbd>RMB</kbd> *> Remap users* and choose the target image.

The remapped images will be removed on closing your .Blend.
(If they don't have a fake user assigned).

[image]
[image]