# Change all references to an image texture

Tags: texturing, image, outliner

I have several different shaders in my .blend file that point to the same image.  Problem is, that image is in the wrong place, so it's showing up magenta on the model.  Is there a way (perhaps using the outliner) to re-point all references of one image to another image?

Comment: Hi :). You're actually asking two things at once. To repair broken links [use this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/96587/78972). To remap all references to a different image [use this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/164232/78972)

Answer (score 0):

you can use this python script:

```
import bpy


for ob in bpy.context.scene.objects:

    if ob.empty_display_type == "IMAGE":
        if ob.data.filepath == "/old_path/old_file_name.png":
            ob.data.filepath = "/new_path/new_file_name.png"
```